# Is there a way to make the compiler automatically hit a statement(breakpoint) once in catch clause

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Currently I have to set breakpoints in my catch clauses. I wanted to know if there was a way that once in a catch clause the compiler automatically highlights a certain statement. Right now i have to set a break point in my exception handler so that my compiler lets me know that it had entered an exception handler.I am using VS2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `__debugbreak();` (comes from `<intrin.h>`) inside your `catch` clause and the IDE will stop whenever `__debugbreak();` is reached.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of such a functionality.

However, if you go to `Debug > Exceptions` in the menu, you can toggle exception types for which the debugger will break when they're thrown. I know that's not the same as when they're caught, but you should be able to reach a `catch` statement by a few "Step into/over" steps from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `ASSERT(FALSE)`, which will cause the debugger to stop on that line for a debug build.

Comment: It says Identifier Assert is undefined. Is there a header for that ?

Comment: Yes but I don't know it off-hand.  :-)  Use Alexey Frunze's answer instead, as ASSERT is just a macro that eventually turns into __debugbreak() anyway.

Comment: It's `assert(false)` - all lowercase, and it comes from `#include <cassert>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear: at least as a I understand the situation, you want a breakpoint on a particular line, but *only* when/if a particular catch clause was executed. If that's what you want, there are ways to do things, though (to my knowledge) you'll probably have to modify your code a little to make it work.

I, at least, would do this by:

1. creating a global variable, something like: `bool exception_caught;`
2. In the relevant catch clause, adding `exception_caught = true;`
3. Making the breakpoint conditional on `exception_caught`

Offhand, I don't remember exactly how you created a conditional break-point in VS 2010. In 2012, you can set the break-point as usual (e.g., with F9) then right-click the red dot that shows up, and select `condition...` from the pop-up menu. In old versions, you had to bring up the "breakpoints" window separately (but as I recall, the menu entry for it was somewhat difficult to find).